# Merge multiple polygons in separate clusters all in the same layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I need to merge each cluster of adjacent parcels into one parcel.  No attributes is needed as this will be used in a spatial join. Please refer to the image as an additional aid to my explanation.

[image]

Comment: I think you should be able to use [Dissolve](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) with the SINGLE_PART option to achieve this.

Comment: Alternatively start editing, select group and merge. Unless you are talking 100's of groups

Comment: Thank you for the replies.  There is no record that I can use to dissolve on - every parcel has unique attributes

Comment: and there are hundreds of groups

Comment: @Hester, the shape of your features is (by default) dissolve field, if nothing is selected as dissolve field. Did you try the options given in the answers? Please do and ask further if needs be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Dissolve your feature class based on shape (no need to specify any field as dissolve field) as **single part** (untick `Create multipart features (Optional)` ). Here you **DO NOT** need to pick any fields as dissolve field,
2. Create a new long field, say Block_ID, and transfer ObjectIDs of the dissolved blocks to this field,
3. Use spatial join to transfer Block_IDs of the previously created dissolved blocks,
4. Dissolve the result of previous step by using Block_ID field transferred via spatial join. This time you will need multiple parts option is selected (leave `Create multipart features (Optional)` ticked).

Comment: Thank you very much for your advise which resolved the issue.  Did not need step 4 though because i needed the attributes of the adjacent parcels that made out the dissolved parcel.

Comment: @Hester, can you please mark this as the answer then?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below workflow suggested by ESRI:

**Buffer polygons and dissolve those that overlap**

1. In ArcToolbox, select Analysis Tools > Proximity > Buffer.
2. Add the Input Features.
3. Specify an Output Feature Class.
4. Click the 'Dissolve Type (Optional)' in the dropdown list and select Dissolve All.
5. Click OK.
6. Double-click the Data Management Tools > Features > Multipart To Singlepart tool to explode the multiparts and keep the dissolved features as one.

**Reference:**

[How To: Buffer polygons and dissolve those that overlap](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000008225)